# what is the difference between the constants and variables in tensorflow and in normal python program?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the below code i have used the varaibles in tensorflow and in normal code, I do not find any change in the logic, could someone please help me in understanding what is the difference between tensorflow attributes and the normal one:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(3)
b = tf.Variable(8)
c = 9
d = tf.Variable(a+b+c)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    d.initializer.run()
    print(d.eval())

Output: 20
```

In short what is the difference between a,b and c in above code?